# Failed SQLEXPRESS Connection Strings: error 4060

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to check my SQLEXPRESS connection strings through a VB.NET script.
It displays this exception:

> Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-PST'
>   Error number :4060 , state 1 , class 11.

and this is my VB.NET script:

```
Dim connString As String
        If (String.Compare(login, "") = 0 And String.Compare(pwd, "") = 0) Then
            connString = "data source=" + server + ";initial catalog=" + database + ";integrated security=True;"
        Else
            connString = "data source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + ";persist security info=True;user id=" + login + ";password=" + pwd + " ;"

        End If
```

Comment: That error suggests you're using a trusted connection. I *assume* therefore that  the user `DESKTOP-PST` doesn't have a login on the server. Is it a local or remote host? If it's a remote host, then you need to be in a domain to use Windows Authentication, so you either need a domain or need to use SQL Authentication instead.

Comment: Try connecting with SSMS manually by using your credential and check whether its connecting or not

Comment: I'm connecting to a local Database and it is working on SSMS

Comment: If you're building a connection string, it's a good idea to use an [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) as it will take care of any quoting and escaping as necessary.

Comment: @IhebOMRI In SSMS, does `SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` give a result of `WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-PST`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton No it doesn't exist

Comment: It was revealed that WORKGROUP is within computer settings, under "Computer name, domain and workgroup settings" but I don't know why this exception occurs .